# Is it possible to configure some columns in an extJS grid panel to be un-editable?

Tags: extjs

All the solutions that I see require event handlers that filter based on column index or name. I can't believe that there's no way to do this in the configuration of the grid to begin with?

UPDATE: I'm using extJs 4.0 and I'm creating a Ext.grid.Panel

Comment: Haha at the downvote. SO is becoming a very petty place.

Answer (score 4):

Actually column is un-editable be default. It becomes editable when you set [editor](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-editor) config.

This is from [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing) for Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing:

> If an editor is not specified for a particular column then that cell will not be editable and it will be skipped when activated via the mouse or the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question ("is-it-possible-to-configure-some-columns-in-an-extjs-grid-panel-to-be-un-editable") literally and ignore your closing comment that you "can't believe that there's no way to do this in the configuration of the grid to begin with".

Yes its possible.  Create an xtype that extends GridPanel, then have this xtype implement the beforecellselect event to seek a custom config option (e.g. 'uneditable') which should probably be an array, and then return false if the column index or name matches.

Comment: So it can't be done with configuration? That's what I thought. Pretty inconsistent of extJ.

Comment: They can't possibly make everything configurable though I agree this is a good candidate.  See the second answer though, there's a lot missing out of your question that could help better answer your question.  For instance, are you on ExtJS3 or 4?  If 3 there is the EditorGridPanel, which I assumed.  If 4, there is the CellEditing plugin, which the second answer assumes.

Comment: I will update my question I'm using extJs 4.0 and I'm creating a Ext.grid.Panel

Comment: This link suggests you can, but I tried that and it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913467/ext-js-how-to-disable-cell-editing-for-individual-cells-in-a-grid No errors though

Comment: @Rhubarb, your link suggests you can disable the whole row (**not column**).

Answer (score 0):

Yes some columns can be definitely be made uneditable as required
it goes on like this

1. get the cell editing plugin of the grid and bind the beforeedit event

   ```
   var plugin = grid.getPlugin('your_cell_editing_plugin_name');
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(plugin)) {
        plugin.on('beforeedit',this.gridBeforeEdit,this);
    }
   ```
2. here is what to do when beforeedit gets called

   ```
   gridBeforeEdit: function(editor, e, eOpts ) {
       var me          = this,
           editedField = e.field;
       if(editedField == "your_need_to_be_uneditable_fld"){ 
             return false;
        }
    },
   ```